# Can't display retrieved data with raw html angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

i'm trying to display retrieved content by ajax in raw html. 
Here's my code in one file:

```
 <html ng-app="fetch">
<head>
<title>Вывод с базы</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>С базы вывод</h1>
      <div ng-controller="dbCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchFilter" class="form-control">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>News title</th>
                    <th>News description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="news in data | filter:searchFilter">
                    <td>{{news.title}}</td>
                    <td ng-bind-html='data'>{{news.description}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
    angular.module('fetch', ['ngSanitize']).controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("/ajax.php")
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
            })
            .error(function() {
                $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
            });
    }]);
</script>

</html>
```

But output of `<td ng-bind-html='data'>{{news.description}}</td>` this part not accept html tags.
Output is: [Object, object] and etc.

Here's my ajax.php

```
<?php
 //database settings
$conn=new mysqli("1", "1", "1", "1");
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8mb4");

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from rss where          source='tengrinews.kz' limit 20");

 $data = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $data[] = $row;
      }
      echo json_encode($data);
      ?>
```

I've add the angular-sanitize and ngSanitize to my module, what is the problem?

Comment: Your actual data will be in `.data` field. Change the assignment of your data to the scope variable to `$scope.data = data.data;`

Comment: @Chinni no, it doesn't work. Title doesn't have any html tags and easily displayed and my description too, but description shows with html tags. If i delete the ng-bind-html attribute/

Comment: First, this -> `<td ng-bind-html='data'>{{news.description}}</td>` is incorrect, or you use ng-bind-html or you use interpolation, which property has `html` tags? The `description`?

Comment: @developer033 description has html tags.

Comment: So just change to `<td ng-bind-html="news.description"></td>`

Comment: @developer033 thank you, i really tried this solution before. But i guess i've forget to add ngSanitize :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `ng-bind-html` and interpolation `{{}}` together.

So if you want to show the `description`, you should change

**this:**

```
<td ng-bind-html='data'>{{news.description}}</td>
```

**for:**

```
<td ng-bind-html="news.description"></td>
```

**Note:** If you want to display the `object data`, you must use [**JSON filter**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json)(otherwise it'll be rendered as `[object Object]`) and create a new *cell* `<td>` to display it:

```
<td ng-bind="data | json"></td>
```